# How Hibernate ensure DB data integrity?

Tags: hibernate

How will Hibernate ensure that the DB data is not compromised by any means(including back end change). Say for instance if I have loaded some employee data using hibernate, mean while someone modified some column (say salary) using back end tools. Now when I try to save the entity in hibernate cache, how will hibernate checks if data is same as was fetched?

Comment: it won't, what would you want it to do ?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e2835, https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/OptimisticLocking.html

Comment: @NimChimpsky : I wanted to know if there is any mechanism by which I can ensure that data integrity is maintained. If my application is the only means to update and employee detail and by any mean if someone tries to modify the data from backend, say DBA, then is there any way hibernate can identify that the cached object has been modified before saving into DB.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks for the info. Optimistic locking works fine but i want to check for a scenario where DBA is trying to modify a particular column of an entity, except version column. In that case hibernate will not be able to identify if the entity is still the same.

Comment: @NitinSaxena except if you use the `ALL` OptimisticLockType https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/OptimisticLockType.html#ALL